# Getting Facebook Code+AccessToken In Identity server 4

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) setup using Facebook for authentication.
This is very plug and play

```
.AddFacebook("facebook", options =>
            {

                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.ClientId = "xxx";
                options.AppSecret = "xxx";
            });
```

I can see that during the authentication I am recieving the code needed to request the access token, I'm struggling at how to get this code (or the accesstoken) during the login process, I have a list of all the claims just no tokens.

[image]

I've searched a lot regarding this and [https://andrewlock.net/](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-oauth-2-using-facebook-in-asp-net-core/) is helpful but he doesn't state how he got this code.

Comment: The options class for the FB middleware should expose events that allow you to grab whatever you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.oauth.ioauthevents?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: @mackie I've seen peope use options.Provider(...) but it doesn't seem to exist anymore.  Do you have a code example or website?